# A question about the bundle $G/B \to G/P$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a complex semisimple group. Suppose that $P$ is some parabolic subgroup and let $B \subset P$ denote a Borel subgroup.

Let also $\pi:G/B \to G/P$ be an evident projection.

Consider a $B$-orbit $BwP$ on the parabolic flag variety $G/P$. Let $U \subseteq \pi^{-1}(BwP)$ be the orbit of the maximal dimension.

Is it true that $\pi|_U:U \to BwP$ is a fiber bundle with fiber isomorphic to the affine space?